# Unable to get user location in android

Tags: android

Everytime I run the code below, the log spits out "no location". I do not know where I am going wrong.

I have enabled the location services in the manifest like so :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I should point out that I tried running this app on my nexus 4(API 22), and on the virtual device (API 16, 21, 22) but to no avail.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;
Location location;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

    try {
         location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.d("SE", e.getMessage());
    }

    if (location != null) {

        Log.i("Location Info", "Location achieved!");

    } else {

        Log.i("Location Info", "No location :(");

    }
}
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getLastKnownLocation()` will always return `null`, unless some app on the device has recently requested location updates using the particular location provider.

Use `getLastKnownLocation()` either:

- when you are interested in a location if one happens to be handy, but otherwise can live without it, or
- as an optimization, where you use `requestLocationUpdates()` if `getLastKnownLocation()` either returns `null` or a `Location` that you deem to be too old

See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) for more guidance on when to use the various methods on `LocationManager`.

Answer (score 1):

Because there isn't always a last known location.  If you want to ensure you get a location, register for updates and wait for the location to be determined.  Network will come quickly, GPS may take a while.  Although both have a chance of failing, for example if you aren't connected to wifi/cellular even network will fail, GPS will fail if it can't line of sight enough satellites.